# How change java console font to italic

Tags: java, fonts, console

How change user input font in java console from traditional font to font italic? I use java.util.scanner.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't depend of Java, but on the operating system. And I am not sure if any op system allows this. Console is meant for clean text input/output, not for formatting.

Comment: If you are using some IDE, like Eclipse, then it is possible to change console font for the build-in console.

Comment: I'm sorry. I want only user's input is shown in italic. Like that: Enter a move: (italic)something

Comment: Apart from built-in consoles in IDEs, I don't believe it is possible. Maybe some hidden shenanigan in registry or something like that, but I am sceptical.